# Do not encode parameters in RestSharp

Tags: restsharp

I am using RestSharp to access a RubyOnRails API.
As you might know, RoR likes when the parameters names are in the form `model_name[property]`. RestSharp, on the other hand, does not like it.

Fiddler says I send this to the server :

```
user%5Bemail%5D=user%40email.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=test
```

It looks like R# encodes both the parameters and values when it sends the data (unlike Curl, which looks like it encodes selectively).
While that's fine most of the time I guess, in this particular case, it makes the API return a 401 because it doesn't understand the parameters.

Is it possible to ask R# to not encode the request's parameters ?

Thank you !

**Edit**

Ok, in the R# sources, I found the method RestClient.EncodeParameters, so it looks like the parameter's name is always encoded. I guess I will have to fork it :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[In the RestSharp sources](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/fe2b032d4e3601a93cf51a2db58f23efbe3e04ac/RestSharp/RestClient.cs#L415) I found out that the parameters are always encoded (both the name and the value), so I guess that I will have to fork it if I want to add an additional parameter.

Comment: Updated line number: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.cs#L415

Answer (score 14):

Since RestSharp version [106.4.0](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/releasenotes.md) you can just use `ParameterType.QueryStringWithoutEncode` in `request.AddParameter()` function:

```
        request.AddParameter("user_id", @"45454545%6565%65", ParameterType.QueryStringWithoutEncode);
```

Comment: This should now be the accepted solution - since 106.4.0 came out.

Comment: Yeah, I think so

Answer (score 5):

I know this has already been answered, but I wanted to add this answer since it worked for me. There is an (albeit hacky) solution to this. Build your own uri for parameters that should not be encoded.

```
var uri = string.Concat("/path/to/your/api", "?paramThatShouldNotBeEncoded=", DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).ToString("O"));
var restRequest = new RestRequest(uri, Method.GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: probably doesn't work in most cases from comments.

I found an interesting solution... Just decode the parameters you want to pass in and restsharp will encode back to what it should be.  For example, I have an api key that uses %7 in it and RestSharper further encodes it.  I decoded the api key and passed that into RestSharp and it seems to work!

Comment: That is unfortunate, this might have been an edge case. I believe it was an error with a MapQuest API key that I resolved by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

See this PR from the project site:
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/pull/1157

However, as far as I can tell, it's not yet in a release on NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```cs
request.AddQueryParameter("sendEndDate", "string:data,something-else", false);
```

This is the function in the metadata of `RestSharp.IRestRequest`:

```cs
IRestRequest AddQueryParameter(string name, string value, bool encode);
```