# Prevent encoding of RestSharp parameters

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to call an `OAuth2` API with the scope parameter set t o `read,usercp`. However RestSharp always encodes the parameter to `&scope=read%2Cusercp` where instead it should be `&scope=read,usercp`

I have not yet found a way to disable the encoding for a single parameter.

Here's my code:

```
var request = GetRequest("index.php?oauth/token", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("client_id", ClientId);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", ClientSecret);

request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
request.AddParameter("username", username);
request.AddParameter("password", password);
request.AddParameter("scope", "read,usercp");

//request.Parameters.Add(new Parameter
//{
//    ContentType = "application/json",
//    Name = "scope",
//    Value = "read,usercp"
//});

var response = await RestClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<AuthenticateResponse>(request);
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK &&
    response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
{
    throw new Exception("Could not authenticate user");
}
```

How do I disable encoding of that single parameter?

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22166701/4499267) answer, it seems that they are always encoded.
I've also found an open issue on github: http://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/892

Comment: @Phate01 Thank you. Maybe there's a workaround for that? I cannot seem to find one.

Comment: See same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098878/do-not-encode-parameters-in-restsharp/52743293#52743293

Answer (score -3):

As I assume you want the comma to be treated exactly as it is written in your code, I would suggest using a verbatim string escaping. 
Not entirely sure how RestSharp handles this but you could try either:

```
    request.AddParameter("scope", @"read,usercp");
```

or you escape it in a string separately:

```
    var sScope = @"read,usercp";
    request.AddParameter("scope", sScope);
```