# How to not encode RestSharp parameter

Tags: c#, restsharp

I need to pass one of parameters to HttpRequest (POST).

Lets say we have '**someParam**' parameter and we need to pass '**some+value**' value.

When using **request.AddParameter("someParam", "some+value");** - value is automatically converted to '**some%2Bvalue**' and in request it looks like '**someparam=some%2Bvalue**'. But the application only understands **+**.

**Is there any way how to add parameter to request but don't encode it???**

Answer (score 1):

On server side should be 'some%2Bvalue' decoded to "some+value". If it is not, better solution for you is to separate values to:

```
request.AddParameter("someParam", "some");
request.AddParameter("someParamValue", "value");
```

And on server side just parse parameters to `some+value` as you wanted.

Another workaround would be to replace string "%2" with "+". But still it is better approach to separate values.

Possible workaround for GET:

```
    string resource = "something";
    var client = new RestClient(baseurl+ resource +"?"+"someParam"+"="+"some+value");
    var request = new RestRequest(resource, method);
    IRestResponse<T> response = client.Execute<T>(request);
    return response.Data;
```

So you have to compose url by yourself and provide it whole to request.

Comment: Thank for responding. But the issue is that I can't change the API on server as it is not mine. Also server replaces '+' by space. More practical example if I need to add 'Big Star' value to 'companyName' param, but if I pass value as 'Big Star' or 'Big%20Star' or 'Big%2BStar' the server throws the error, the only I can pass is 'Big+Star': request.AddParameter("companyName", "Big+Star"); doesn't work as it's automatically encode '+'

Comment: So the main intent that I need to send '+' in not encoded way (looks like RestSharp forcing special symbol to encode them and there is no such flag to notice it to not be encoded)

Comment: You should contact owner. Because encoding is part of http protocol. Node.js is decoding it properly for me for example and ASP.NET too. So for me it seems to be bad server implementation.

Comment: Exact, its a bad server implementation :-) so I was searching for solution to bypass it (make a workaround) if it wouldn't be fixed by owner. Thanks :-)

Comment: If you could use GET I edited answer, how to do it. But in case of post I´m afraid you would have to sacrifice restsharp and go deeper.

Comment: Yeah, with Get or adding url segment it works ok, but for post..(( Ok will contact owner

Comment: This answer, and the comments below completely ignore the spirit of the question and ignore the fact that sending a '+' in POST data is completely legal.  The server implementation is fine, it is RestSharp that has the problem.  Obviously this is several years later, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098878/do-not-encode-parameters-in-restsharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode
```

for example:

```
var url = getUrlFromConfig();
var params = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("$foo/bar?someParam={some}&someParamValue={value}");
var client = new RestClient(apiUrl + params);
```

This will generate a valid url without your problem.